# Adding variable number of zeroes to make a six digit number

Tags: php, prefix

I am working with a membership database which records all accounts in a six digit format however, some users will be using a sub-six digit format due to older conventions.  So I want to be able to accept a sub-six digit number and prefix zeroes to the beginning of it.

e.g.
user enters number 1234, I want PHP to format it to become 001234.
user enters number 123, I want PHP to format it to become 000123.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use PHPs [`sprintf()`-function](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$formattedNumber = sprintf('%06d', $unformattedNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

Too Easy

```
str_pad($input, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
<?php
$id= sprintf("%06d", $id);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$padded_num = str_pad($num, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Padded numbers must be represented as strings for output.

Comment: It says on http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php that the third parameter (the 0) should be a string (enclosed in quotes), like in the example below. While the code above seems to work, it's probably best to use the code below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_pad function:

```
str_pad($number, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_num = str_pad($Num, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```